# ASP.NET MVC 4 Required Validation client side on Radio Buttons

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a series of radio buttons, one must be selected whent he user clicks the submit button:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(o => o.EquityOrder.OrderAction, EnumOrderAction.B, new {id = "actionBuy"})
@Html.RadioButtonFor(o => o.EquityOrder.OrderAction, EnumOrderAction.S, new {id = "actionSell"})
```

Is there a way to ensure that the form doesn't submit and the  @Html.ValidationSummary() is populated with a "OrderAction must be selected" string?

Comment: Have you tried DataAnnotations in your model?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just tag the `OrderAction` property in your model with this:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "OrderAction must be selected")]
```

I assume you have client validation enabled in either the web.config or the view and you have included the jquery validation file.

Comment: How do you do it for `@Html.RadioButton` ?

Comment: you must write `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` to display error message. if show validation summary is not set to true.